# What does the size element in $_FILE represent?

Tags: php, file, file-upload

I like to ask something that may be simple and stupid, but I can't find out that information in PHP documentation.

Does the `$_FILE['field_name']['size']` field represent the file size in bytes ?

Comment: I was searched for that info here http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=php+%24_FILES

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa Do you have any better suggestion for title ?

Comment: @Timur I have try that, but the first result in my Country is not the correct one. alickus and Alister Bulman gave me the correct link. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes,

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: Thanks a lot !! I used that page http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php that doesn't have that info

Comment: I have 5 minutes yet !! ;) I will accept your answer ! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[file uploads info](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) (on php.net)

```
$_FILES['userfile']['size']
    The size, in bytes, of the uploaded file.
```